# Dunn's post-hoc Test after Kruskal, 'which one is more effective?' after significant difference

Tags: anova, python, kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

Dunn's test yielded the result that there is a significant difference in revenue between group 1 and group 2 after Kruskal.

In classic one way ANOVA case, if the result is same as above, you see whether 95% CI revenue of the two groups overlap each other in order to figure out "which group is more effective at increasing revenue than which significantly".

But Dunn's test uses mean rank, not mean. To get the answer to the same question, do I have to calculate 95% CI around median and see if the two groups overlap?

Or, can I just compare the two groups' median revenues to say that one is more effective than the other?

How do you see which one is more effective at increasing revenue when there is a significant difference between two groups (pair) after Dunn's test?

Also, is there a method equivalent to Tukey's .plot_simultaneous() for Dunn's in python?

Comment: The Dunn (1964) test compares the groups pairwise, so there's no need to look at 95% confidence intervals of some parameter estimates to determine is the groups are different.  (This is the same as post-hoc testing after a one-way anova).  Technically, the sign of the test statistic will indicate which group has observations with larger values than the other (though I don't know what the output from Python looks like.)  Practically speaking, which group has larger values should be obvious from plotting the original values in some meaningful way, or plotting or summarizing the ranked values.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Thank you for the answer!